# How to send request to a server over local network

Tags: java, spring, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I have made a server. It receives user's name and sends it back to user. I want my server to run on my laptop using tomcat e.g(localhost/test). Now i want to send request to this sever from another computer which is within the local network using java...? I have send request to localhost server using httpClient library..but how to send request to server over the local notwork?

Comment: By using the IP of your server in your network. Probably something like http://192.168.x.x/test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your local network is configured on a TCP/IP you should not have any problems.  Just find the IP address for you laptop (let say for example 192.168.0.1) and from the client that uses the httpClient library just call 192.168.0.1/test

Don't forget to check the permissions for the proper port if your laptop server is behind a Firewall.

Comment: Thanks man it seeeeeems fine to me...but let me check and than comment back if it is working or not.